# Neo4j 2.1.1 concern - consistency check of community edition db

Tags: neo4j

Following on from the information found in [the blog post titled 'Neo4j 2.1.2 – Maintenance Release'](http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-1-2/), I thought I should check the consistency of a database that has been upgraded to Neo4j 2.1.1.

My set up: Neo4j community edition running on Windows Server 2012 R2 - the binary distribution running as a Windows service (NOT the windows desktop launcher executable).

In the blog post it talks about using the backup tool included with the enterprise version of Neo4j so I have downloaded an evaluation copy (2.1.4) so have access to Neo4jBackup.bat. I cannot however, get a backup to run. No matter what I try I get

*Couldn't connect to '127.0.0.1:6362'*

or a variation thereof.

I am running

```
.\bin\Neo4jBackup.bat -from localhost -to D:\DataBackups\Neo4j\check
```

I have tried specifying a port, specifying IP address, using `single://localhost`. After consulting the manual more closely I have also amended my config to add

```
# Enable online backups to be taken from this database.
online_backup_enabled=true

# Port to listen to for incoming backup requests.
online_backup_server=127.0.0.1:6362
```

Still I receive the same error. I am clearly being a moron. What am I doing wrong? Help!

The question boils down to 'how do I back up a community edition database as alluded to [in this Neo4j blog post](http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-1-2/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so yes. I am a moron. It just came to me. You need to open the database with the enterprise edition!

For anyone who is overcome with a moment of stupidity, like me

1. Copy the database you wish to check (graph.db by default) to the data directory of your evaluation copy of Neo4j
2. Start up Neo4j (you may or may not need a store upgrade)
3. Run .\bin\Neo4jBackup.bat -from localhost -to [your desired backup location]
4. Sit back and await the results

Feel free to mock/throw rotten vegetables etc at me....! :)

Comment: This is not supposed to be accepted answer, because its using enterprise to answer community (at least in title)...

Comment: @PavelNiedoba - I am sorry but I don't agree. IMHO it is absolutely the answer and the only way to do what I was trying to do. Rather than delete the question, I left the question and answered it as I believed it might be useful for anyone else who was confused. In fact the blog post linked to now mentions using an evaluation license of the enterprise edition to perform the consistency check on a community edition database, i.e. the very method I put here. I am sorry if you still disagree. We'll have to agree to disagree! :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the 2.1 line (somewhere around 2.1.5 I think) the consistency checker was moved from the enterprise edition to the community edition. It is therefore now possible to check a DB with the community edition too. In the root of the neo4j server directory run:

```
java -cp 'lib/*' org.neo4j.consistency.ConsistencyCheckTool data/graph.db
```

Note that this is not an offical API (it's undocumented).

Comment: In Neo4j 3, the database has moved, so the command is now: `java -cp 'lib/*' org.neo4j.consistency.ConsistencyCheckTool data/databases/graph.db`